# Is there any risk in leaving a Li-ion connected to a solar panel with only step-down converter?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, buck, safety, solar-energy

I have a 18V solar panel which is connected to a step-down buck converter, which drops the voltage from 18V to 3.5V. When clouds block the sun, the voltage drops to less than 3.1V. I have added a diode on the positive terminal to make sure that the battery doesn't give back any current, but I was wondering if there is any risk in having such a fluctuation. Li-ion is sensible to trickle-voltage, and I am worried that this kind of of fluctuations will destroy the battery. Is this fear motivated by reality?

Right now, I'm only connecting the wires to the battery when it is full sun, because I have a constant voltage more or less. Can I keep this connection all the time or do I need other components to keep the battery safe?

Comment: Li-ion requires more than just a constant electric potential (constant voltage). At lower charge levels and other charging states, a constant current is commonly used.

Comment: Yes, but the current is related to the voltage and resistance. The resistance is the same, but the voltage will be different. Therefore different current, right? And that worries me, because different voltage mean different current, ergo no CC charging regime. Or did I understand this one wrong?

Comment: A battery is not a resistor. Until it's got to the state of charge where you can use CV charging you need to use constant current charging. Applying too large a voltage in that time could result in using far too much current.

Comment: Yes. And this confirms my worries, as fluctuation in voltage for at SoC < 0.8 means unstable (no CC) current. Is this correct?

Comment: If you don't REALLY understand how to charge lithium batteries, either learn (good resources on ti.com) or don't mess with them.  Alternately, place your whole assembly in a concrete fireproof bunker and stay out when it's operational.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am not using them when I'm not around and when I'm not 100% sure that it is fine. I'm always reading about it and asking around when I don't know something before actually starting working with them

Comment: I believe that floating a lithium ion battery at 3.5V is unlikely to cause it to vent or explode. However, it will only have a small fraction of its rated capacity in this case. You should confirm/determine that the maximum charge current is not excessive. If it is, then do not charge it. Also, make sure you do NOT charge the battery when it is cold (let us just say that if it is below freezing, make sure you do not charge the battery at all).

Comment: @mkeith good advice, but the OP states there is a diode in series with the supply, so presumably he/she is trying to charge at around 2.8 (Si diode) or 3.2 (Schottky) volts, which is unlikely to be satisfactory.  Far better to buck or buck-boost to a higher voltage and use a dedicated Li battery charger or Li MPPT charger to manage the charge profiles.

Comment: Yeah. Even 3.5 is unlikely to be satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are using just use a propper board. It will charge better and the risk is going to be smaller.

Search on eBay or Aliexpress for [CN3791](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1-cell-lithium-battery-3-7-V-4-2V-lithium-battery-CN3791-MPPT-solar-controller/32851594991.html). The board is less than 4$ and does eveything properly.

If you are curious to learn about it, read [it's datasheet](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3791.pdf).